# Transact-SQL Count using a subselect statement filtering on a variable from top select

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, count, subquery

I'm trying to include account of records associated with a particular user in the same row as other information about the user. Something like:

```
select
    au.UserName as UsersName,
    Count(
        select sg.Id from sg
        where sg.Username = UsersName
     )

...
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Put the `count()` inside the `select`:

```
select au.UserName as UsersName,
       (select count(sg.Id)
        from sg
        where sg.Username = au.UserName
       )
```

The correlation also cannot use the column alias.  It needs to use the part before the `as`.  The alias is outside the scope of the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Use column name instead of alias name

```
select
    au.UserName as UsersName,
    (
        select count(sg.Id) from sg
        where sg.Username = au.UserName
     ) as Count
...
```

DEMO
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b62d/10

Comment: Will the value selected for au.Username be the same as the one chosen outside of the subselect statement?

Comment: This works, thanks. Putting count() inside the select is what did it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select au.UserName as UsersName, count(sg.Id)
  from au 
  join sg 
    on sg.Username = au.UserName
 group by au.UserName
```